# error with label.text and NSNumber

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I would like to do this:
I have a dictionary like this:

```
[myMutableDictionary setValue:myNSNumber forKey:@"myKey"];
```

myNSNumber is an NSNumber.

```
myCell.label.text = [self.myMutableDictionary objectForkey@"myKey"];
```

I have an error when I assign the number stored in my dictionary to my label in myCell.
The error is:

> je suis la  2011-05-02 15:01:01.264 []
>   -[NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x225d00 2011-05-02 15:01:01.319 []
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x225d00'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`NSNumber`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is not an `NSString` and the text of the label needs to set to an `NSString`.

```
NSNumber *num = (NSNumber*)[self.myMutableDictionnary objectForkey@"myKey"];
myCell.label.text = [num stringValue];
```

Comment: ok thanks. i will do this : NSNumber *num = (NSNumber*)[self.myMutableDictionnary objectForkey@"myKey"]; for all my NSNumber for each one, or can i do it one time to all my NSNumber in my dictionnary

Comment: Each time you access an NSNumber you will need to call stringValue. The following will work: `myCell.label.text = [(NSNumber*)[self.myMutableDictionnary objectForkey@"myKey"] stringValue];`

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do it by 2 ways

first is myCell.label.text = [[self.myMutableDictionnary objectForkey@"myKey"] stringValue];

second is myCell.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[self.myMutableDictionnary objectForkey@"myKey"]] ;